# What causes this strange mutation on my Roma tomato?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, tomatoes, genetics

I'm curious, is this a mutation or something else? This is a store bought Roma plant so I do not know the genetics. The tomato fell off whilst I was collecting my harvest around 8/8/22. It didn't take much for the tomato to pop off the vine. It looks like two Roma tomatoes stacked on top of one another. Other people have said it is a single Roma tomato with a very tight waistband. I have not attempted to pull them apart because I am waiting to see how this ripens. I've been growing tomatoes for 23 years and I have never see an abnormality like this.

FWIW: Zone 6a

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be zippering.

Comment: I had a San Marzano tomato do that just a few weeks ago. It ripened just fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by fasciation at the flower stage - two flowers are conjoined and produce a fruit with the same condition. It can occur in any fruiting plant; causes are varied, from a genetic blip to bacterial, fungal or viral infections in the plant (but you'd notice other symptoms if it was one of those), herbicide damage or environmental causes. Most often it's just a genetic blip... https://www.chicagobotanic.org/tomatotalk_june27